# Error: invalid_request Missing required parameter: scope (Restify & Passportjs w/ Google OAuth2)

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, google-oauth, restify

So, I've run into a problem with my Node.js app, using Restify and Passportjs (Google OAuth2 strategy). When I use `passport.authenticate()`, it gives me the following error:

> 400. That’s an error.
>   Error: invalid_request
>   Missing required parameter: scope

I found another question about the same thing from a couple of years ago ([invalid_request with missing: scope using Google Passportjs on Google Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931847/invalid-request-with-missing-scope-using-google-passportjs-on-google-oauth2?newreg=02cf8c8315244b2e8b2a1aefcb4ebc3a)). The author said he finally fixed it himself but didn't post the fix.

Has anyone else run into this and been able to fix it? I can't figure it out. Here is my code:

**authController.js**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;

var auth = {
  google: {
    clientID: '<ID>',
    clientSecret: '<SECRET>',
    callbackURL: 'https://localhost:8080/auth/google/return',
    scope: ['profile', 'email']
  }
};

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: auth.google.clientID,
    clientSecret: auth.google.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: auth.google.callbackURL
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
  return cb(null, profile.id);
}));

module.exports.authenticate = passport.authenticate('google', { scope: auth.google.scope });
module.exports.isAuthenticated = passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/hello/succeed', failureRedirect: '/hello/fail' });
```

**server.js**

```
var restify = require('restify'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    authController = require('./controllers/authController');

// Placeholder handler.
function respond(req, res, next) {
  res.send('hello ' + req.params.name);
  return next();
}

// Create server.
var api = restify.createServer({
  certificate: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  name: 'BQ:IQ Question Writer'
});

// Setup authentication
api.get('/auth/google', authController.authenticate);
api.get('/auth/google/return', authController.isAuthenticated);

// Setup routes.
api.get('/hello/:name', respond);
api.head('/hello/:name', respond);

api.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', api.name, api.url);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I was missing the following code after initializing the server:

```
api.use(restify.plugins.queryParser({ mapParams: false }));
```

Once I added that line, I no longer saw the Google error, and the process passed back to my code.